# Control Android recovery mode using Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, android

Is there any way that I could alter the recovery mode on my Android phone using Ubuntu? I'm wondering because my rooted LG Spirit H422 phone crashed when I tried to convert KingRoot to SuperSU, and I can't boot into recovery mode. After it crashed only the LG logo is appearing, so I tried factory reset, but it doesn't work. Now I can't open recovery mode, even by pressing Volume Down+power buttons. How to recover it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

1. Enable USB debugging on your Android device. If you can't get into your phone to enable USB debugging on it, skip this step in case USB debugging is already enabled on it.
2. Install Android Debug Bridge CLI tool (*android-tools-adb*). In Ubuntu 14.04 and later open the  terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
   ```
3. Connect your phone to the computer by USB cable.
4. To boot into recovery mode for all Android devices, open the terminal and type:

   ```
   adb reboot recovery
   ```

   This command allows you to boot directly into recovery mode without pushing any buttons on the phone.
5. If adb returns a `device not found` error message, run the following commands to check if your phone appears on the list of devices attached:

   ```
   adb devices  
   fastboot devices
   ```

Comment: can u send the link to download Android Debug Bridge CLI tool pls

Comment: sir it show device not found when i tried adb devices command it remains blank

Comment: If it remains blank or shows `device not found` after running `adb devices` and `fastboot devices` you could also try asking what to do at [Android Enthusiasts Q&A](http://android.stackexchange.com/). Questions at Android Enthusiasts Q&A have to be about Android and/or Android devices.